# Is there a way to color individual elements in a list in Python?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, colorama

I would like to color elements in a `numpy.ndarray`, specifically ones which are of `numpy.int64` type.

For example, how do I color each `1` in the following list, say, red?

```
    L = [1,0,1,0,1]
```

I have tried using colorama. Here is my code. The result is also included.

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

L = [i%2 for i in range(6)]

for i in L[::2]:
    L[i] = Fore.RED + str(i)

print(L)

['\x1b[31m1', '\x1b[31m0', '\x1b[31m1', '\x1b[31m0', '\x1b[31m1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Lists don't have a concept of color. Colorama characters understood by your computer to represent values in different color. If you want to make your list print with certain colors you need to print each item in the list.

Let's say you want to make the 1's red:

```py
for i in range(len(L)):
    if L[i] == 1:
        L[i] = Fore.RED + str(L[i]) + Fore.RESET
print(L)
# [0, '\x1b[31m1\x1b[39m', 0, '\x1b[31m1\x1b[39m', 0, '\x1b[31m1\x1b[39m']

print(', '.join(str(item) for item in L))  # Now prints certain items in red and others normal.
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I'll need to change the output to some other type. My first thought is to use pretty print. Any other ideas?

Comment: pretty print should be fine. If you have the information as an object you can override the `__str__` method and return a colorama formatted string.

Comment: That makes sense, though it's a little outside of my technical skill. Not having color isn't a dealbreaker, for now.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know we cannot store variables in list as colored variable. colorama only prints the variable in color. So your code will be

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

L = [i%2 for i in range(6)]

for i in L[::2]:
    L[i] = str(i)

for item in L:print(Fore.RED+ str(item))
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the init() method and set autoreset to True.

```
from colorama import Fore, init
init(autoreset=True)

L = [i%2 for i in range(6)]
for i,x in enumerate(L):
    if x == 1: L[i] = Fore.RED + str(x)
    else: L[i] = str(x)

for x in L: print(x)
```